# convert css unicode to js

Tags: javascript, css, unicode

I have a couple of emoji  unicodes that works well in css:

```css
    content: "\f410"
    content: "\f2d1"
```

I tries to [output it with javascript](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-insert-unicode-in-javascript), but I failed, I will be so grateful for any suggestion you may offer.

```js
console.log('\f410');
console.log('\Uf410');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `console.log('\uf410');`, lower case `u`.

ps: and maybe you also like something like: `console.log(String.fromCharCode(parseInt('f410',16)))`.